# Uncaught HierarchyRequestError: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The new child element contains the parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

> Uncaught HierarchyRequestError: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The new child element contains the parent.

I just try to append `span9` before `span3` when windows width is less than 767 and I have this error, why is that?

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Optimalisation: Store the references outside the event handler:
  var $window = $(window);
  var $content = $('.content');
  var $cats = $('.span3');

  function checkWidth() {
      var windowsize = $window.width();
      if (windowsize < 767) {
        $content.insertBefore($cats);
      } else if (windowsize > 767) {
        $content.insertAfter($cats);
      }
    }
    // Execute on load
  checkWidth();
  // Bind event listener
  $(window).resize(checkWidth);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content-entry">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span3">span3</div>
    <div class="span9 content">span9/content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: With the code and markup in the question, [that error doesn't occur](https://jsfiddle.net/o0adedw0/). So clearly there's more markup (which isn't surprising).

Comment: Does not seems to throw error. Can you create Snippet with issue?

Comment: Side note: Look at your `checkWidth` function and ask yourself what it does if the width is exactly 767. ;-)

Comment: Add snippet and yes there no error :(

Comment: *"I just try to append `span9` before `span3` when windows `widt`h is `less then 767` and i have this error why is that ?"* Please don't randomly mark up non-code as code (much less marking up **part** of a word as code). (I've fixed it for you.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the error doesn't occur with what you've shown, the error message is quite clear: Apparently, you have at least one element with the class `span3` that's *inside* an element with the class `content`, like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Optimalisation: Store the references outside the event handler:
  var $window = $(window);
  var $content = $('.content');
  var $cats = $('.span3');

  function checkWidth() {
      var windowsize = $window.width();
      if (windowsize < 767) {
        $content.insertBefore($cats);
      } else if (windowsize > 767) {
        $content.insertAfter($cats);
      }
    }
    // Execute on load
  checkWidth();
  // Bind event listener
  $(window).resize(checkWidth);
});
```

```html
<div class=".content-entry">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="content"><!-- Note this new element -->
        <div class="span3">span3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="span9 content">span9</div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The solution is to target your selectors more carefully at just the elements you want to move around. Apparently `content` and/or `span3` are used for other things as well as what you're using them for here.

For instance:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Optimalisation: Store the references outside the event handler:
  var $window = $(window);
  var $content = $('.move-this');     // Changed the class
  var $cats = $('.relative-to-this'); // Changed the class

  function checkWidth() {
      var windowsize = $window.width();
      if (windowsize < 767) {
        $content.insertBefore($cats);
      } else if (windowsize > 767) {
        $content.insertAfter($cats);
      }
    }
    // Execute on load
  checkWidth();
  // Bind event listener
  $(window).resize(checkWidth);
});
```

```html
<div class=".content-entry">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="content"><!-- Note this new element -->
        <div class="span3 relative-to-this">span3</div><!-- Added a class -->
    </div>
    <div class="span9 content move-this">span9</div><!-- Added a class -->
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Trying to understand but no luck..i edit and put a picture of html structure,I don't have any other div with class content or span3 etc..

Comment: @Rav_g: If you're getting that error, you **do** have an instance of `.span3` inside an instance of `.content`.

Comment: Why is that a problem, @T.J.Crowder? I can't seem to get my head around this :S

Comment: @D'T4ils - Because if there's a `.span3` *inside* `.content`, `$content.insertBefore($cats);`/`$content.insertAfter($cats);` tries to insert `$content` elements inside themselves.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder anyway to have it ignore the inner elements? I want to insert the broader elements.

Comment: @KyleCalica-St - Sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean by that.